# How to define https connection in Airflow using environment variables

Tags: airflow

In Airflow http (and other) connections can be defined as environment variables. However, it is hard to use an `https` schema for these connections.

Such a connection could be:

```
export AIRFLOW_CONN_MY_HTTP_CONN=http://example.com
```

However, defining a secure connection is not possible:

```
export AIRFLOW_CONN_MY_HTTP_CONN=https://example.com
```

Because Airflow strips the scheme (`https`) and in the final connection object the url gets `http` as scheme.

It turns out that there is a possibility to use `https` by defining the connection like this:

```
export AIRFLOW_CONN_MY_HTTP_CONN=https://example.com/https
```

The second `https` is called `schema` in the airflow code (like in DSN's e.g. `postgresql://user:passw@host/schema`). This `schema` is then used as the `scheme` in the construction of the final url in the connection object.

I am wondering if this is by design, or just an infortunate mixup of `scheme` and `schema`.

Answer (score 4):

For those who land in this question in the future, I confirm that @jjmurre 's answer works well for 2.1.3 .

In this case we need URI-encoded string.

```
export AIRFLOW_CONN_SLACK='http://https%3a%2f%2fhooks.slack.com%2fservices%2f...'
```

See [this post](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2910?focusedCommentId=16832468&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16832468) for more details.

Hope this can save other fellows an hour which I've spent on investigating.

Comment: To correct encode your URL you can use [quote_plus()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus) like sad [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html#handling-of-special-characters-in-connection-params)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Connections](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/index.html) and then you can specify schema.

Comment: Because of our deployment setup, I need to use enviroment variables. For reproducible deploys we cannot use the webserver gui for configuring our Airflow instance.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet (usage of AIRFLOW_CONN_MY_HTTP_CONN). By default variable cannot be interpreted wrong. Probably, problem is in your usage or in used library.

Comment: http = HttpHook(http_conn_id="my_http_conn", method="POST")

Comment: I subscribed to the Airflow slack channels and asked around about is. Seems, that this is a know issue. One suggestion was to URI-escape the connection string, like e.g. AIRFLOW_CONN_SLACK='http://https%3a%2f%2fhooks.slack.com%2fservices%2f...   See: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2910

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me using bitnami airflow:

.env

```
MY_SERVER=my-conn-type://xxx.com:443/https
```

docker-compose.yml

```
environment:
      - AIRFLOW_CONN_MY_SERVER=${MY_SERVER}
```